# Spring data solr boost - bq clause

Tags: spring-data-solr

We are trying to use spring data solr. We have a heavy need to use boost query (bq)
Is there a way to generate "bq" clause while querying solr using spring data solr?
The field on which we use boost value, is not used for filtering. Say I am looking for televisions made by Sony (filter), but I want to boost on size (47Inch the most). The reason is if there are 47s i can atlease show TVs of different sizes